# React js : event.preventDefault throws exception for react-boostrap menuItem

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

There a onClick event to the menuItem and on clicking it the dropdown is closing. TO avoid that I'm using event.preventDefault but its throwing error like "event.preventDefault is not a function"

code:

```
     constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.itemClick = this.itemClick.bind(this);
        }

        dropdownData = () => {
            return this.props.dropdownData.items.map((item, i) => {
                return (<MenuItem className="dropdown_menuItems"
                    key={i}
                    tabIndex="0"
                    onClick={(e) => this.itemClick(e)}
                    aria-label={item.title}>
                    {item.title}
                </MenuItem>);
            });
        }

        itemClick = (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(event.target.innerHTML,'inner')
        }
 render() {
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={4} md={4} xs={6} lg={4}>
                        <ButtonToolbar>
                            <DropdownButton

                                title={this.state.selectedData}
                                id="dropdown-size-large">
                                {this.dropdownData()}
                              </DropdownButton>
                         </ButtonToolbar>
                      </Col>
                   </Row> 
              </Grid>
```

Comment: maybe this is issue : event.preventdefault(); => event.preventDefault();

Comment: No, Its not working already tried..

Comment: Your code works for me [as-is](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2v5nr933z), but you can try `onClick={this.itemClick}`

Comment: I'm using react v16 and I tried with the above option already, it is closing the dropdown.. event.preventDefault is not working..

Comment: Put `console.log(event)` into `itemClick` as the first expression - you'll see maybe `event` here is not an event at all.

Comment: Weird..!! but we do have onClick for the menuItem which is a callback event..any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

`MenuItem` is not a native element, you should check it's document for more info

Comment: We do have onClick for menuITem https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/ ..